# How can I filter a * intersection * of manytomany field in django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

i want to filter query , and one of field is manytomany .
how to filter intersection in manytomany fields
my model is:

---

```
class Event(models.Model):

    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

---

views:

```
  search_subcategory = Q()
    if subcategory != 'null':
        total_filter.append('subcategory')
        subcategory = subcategory.split(",")
        for i in range(0, len(subcategory)): 
            subcategory[i] = int(subcategory[i])
        for x in subcategory:
            search_subcategory &= Q(subcategory=x)


    search_title = Q()
    if title != '':
        total_filter.append('title')
        search_title = Q(title__icontains=title)


     
    filter_query = Event.objects.filter(search_category & search_title).distinct()
```

but this not working